# How to refer to a defined constant in a PySpark function?

Tags: python, function, pyspark

This feels like a really simple question but I am having a difficult time finding an answer.

I have a function in PySpark that performs a couple calculations:

```
def calculate_value:

    CONSTANT = 25

    new_sdf = sdf.withColumn("corrected_column", spark_fns.expr("old_column * CONSTANT")

    return new_sdf
```

This errors out, so I am wondering what the correct way to refer to a constant variable is?

Comment: I might suggest `spark_fns.expr(f"old_column * {CONSTANT}")`.

Comment: well that was embarrassing. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

CONSTANT = 25
new_sdf = sdf.withColumn("corrected_column", CONSTANT*F.col("old_column"))
```